# AngularJS SPA with ASP.NET Web API back-end

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am new to AngularJS and need some advice on how to structure a SPA with Web API for an internal order entry system (SEO not a concern).  I would like to set this up in a clean, well-structured fashion for efficient development, debug & deployment.

Here is what I am planning to do:

- Not use MVC / razor views (leave all routing and rendering to Angular)
- Create two separate Visual Studio (2013) solutions: one just for the AngularJS SPA portion and one for Web API portion (for serving all data to the SPA).

As an alternative, I guess I could use one Visual Studio solution for the full site (both SPA and WebAPI) and then use razor to serve the html files (or figure out how to disable the default MVC plumbing and serve straight HTML instead, to avoid the MVC overhead).  Also, would I then have to put both the SPA and the WebAPI in the same project to be able to debug with Visual Studio easily?

Or perhaps there is a better approach?

Advice on best practices / good approaches on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Follow google's recommendation for best practices for angular app structure: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub. Do use MVC/razor views for the initial page load and Web API for everything else.   Keep controllers, scripts, resources organized by functional area rather than structurally separate (as per googles guidelines). Do use VS2013 bunding and minification support.

Comment: Do take advantage of MVC controller actions to manage multiple SPAs for any large scale site. There are many advantages to doing this (leverage best practices for ASP.NET security)

Comment: It is OK to use MVC actions/razor views, but mostly for the initial page load, sometimes for redirects to another SPA in the same site.

Comment: Are you looking for both the Angularjs and WebAPI ?

Comment: @pixelbits Thanks - good reference and advice!  So it sounds like I should put both the AngularJS SPA and the WebAPI not only in the same Visual Studio solution, but also in the same project (but of course use different projects for repositories, models, business logic, etc.).  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I think it depends on how you think of your Web API layer. If you think of them as extensions of your MVC controllers, then I would put them in the same project (you might do this if you secure your application by functional area). On the other hand, if they are more like traditional stand alone web services, I would keep them in a separate project. Other configurations are possible as well. I think it comes down to what the needs of your application are.

Answer (score 5):

We have created a two different projects under the same solution , First one is the empty web application and the next one is a class library .

1) Web application project consists of angular JS  and the other client side components .

2) Class library consists of the Web api controllers and the relevant components such as filters and the other details.

We have a bootstrap class in the class library project which bootstraps the webapi and the container for us. Also it makes the testing of Web api easily

```
   public class Bootstrap
   {
        public void ConfigureRoute(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
        {
        }

        public BootStrapApplication ConfigureContainer()
        {
        }
   }
```

From the global.asax in the app_start we call the BootStrap application class and the method .

For application structure on angularjs i found the John papa guide efficient https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide

Hope this helps